# Getting variables in a class?

Tags: python, class, variables

When I try to do this:

```
print(pyfancy.RED + "Hello Red!" + pyfancy.END)
```

RED and END is a variable but when I run it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RED'
```

It worked before now it does not work!

Please Help!

Comment: What is `pyfancy`? Module name or object name?

Comment: Did you `import pyfancy` first?

Comment: Can you provide the code of "pyfancy"?

Comment: @Cyber, he clearly has imported pyfancy as you can see in the error, python recogonizes that it's a module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have a module called `pyfancy` that contains a class, probably also called `pyfancy`(?).

Either write `pyfancy.pyfancy.RED` or import the class like so:

```
from pyfancy import pyfancy
```

(You might need to tweak this to match the actual class name used in your code.)

Answer (score 0):

`RED` is probably a class attribute of a class called `pyfancy` in a module called `pyfancy` - you need to either `from pyfancy import pyfancy` or use `pyfancy.pyfancy.RED`, etc.